# Wordcount C++ Hadoop pipes does not work

Tags: c++, hadoop, cluster-computing, word-count

I am trying to run the example of wordcount in C++ like this link describes the way to do :
[Running the WordCount program in C++](http://cs.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Hadoop_Tutorial_2.2_--_Running_C++_Programs_on_Hadoop). The compilation works fine, but when I tried to run my program, an error appeared :

> bin/hadoop pipes -conf ../dev/word.xml -input testtile.txt -output wordcount-out 
>   11/06/06 14:23:40 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be 
> found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
>   11/06/06 14:23:40 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
>   11/06/06 14:23:40 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201106061207_0007
>   11/06/06 14:23:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
>   11/06/06 14:23:53 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201106061207_0007_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
>   java.io.IOException
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.OutputHandler.waitForAuthentication(OutputHandler.java:188)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Application.waitForAuthentication(Application.java:194)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Application.(Application.java:149)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.PipesMapRunner.run(PipesMapRunner.java:68)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:435)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:371)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:259)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:253)
>   attempt_201106061207_0007_m_000000_0: Server failed to authenticate. Exiting

I am running Hadoop on Fedora on two nodes, and I followed instructions for configurations from that link : [Running Hadoop on multi-node cluster](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/). I tried the wordcount example of Hadoop with that command :

> bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-0.20.203.0.jar wordcount testtile.txt wordcount-out

And that command works fine. That is why I don't understand why my program did not work. So I hope that someone have an idea about what I am doing wrong, or if someone had already resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if I have to answer to my question in this way, or edit my question. Anyway I find the solution and I just want to tell it for everyone who will get the same error.

After few days of research and try, I understand that Fedora and C++ on 64bits for Hadoop is not a good match. I tried to compile the Hadoop wordcount C++ with ant like explained in the wiki. But ant gets me some error about : libssl and stdint.

First, if you are on Fedora you have to add **-lcrypto** to the **LIBS** variables in the *.configure*. That is cause the dependency on libcrypto must now be explicitely stated on these platform when linking to libssl.(see [bug on Fedora](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/DISTRO-38)).

Second issue : ant produces a lot of error about C++ files : to resolve that you just have to add an include : *stdint.h* on the top of the file.

Then the build success. I tried then to run wordcount example on my Hadoop cluster and it works, while mine did not. I expected that issue come from the library that I just corrected and I was right : I tried to run Hadoop example with library from the hadoop install directory and it did not work and I get the same error.

That could be explained by the fact that ant recompile the C++ library needed for Hadoop(with correction that I did) and used it, instead library provides in the Hadoop install directory.

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you get no other acceptable answers, you're quite welcome to answer your own question if you find a solution yourself. Thanks for your follow-up.